# A problem with a Plot of a PDF

Tags: plotting

I have the following:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]A = ProbabilityDistribution[{"PDF", Piecewise[{{((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2), x <  P <= -(x/(-1 + f))}, {(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2), x/(1 + f) <=  P <=  x}}, 0]}, {P, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < x <= 1/2, 0 < f < 1}]
```

and now I am attempting:

```
With[{f = 0.25, x = 0.25}, Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]A, P], {P, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]]
```

but my chart shows nothing. I suspect that is because there is something wrong with my PDF (although Mathematica is silent on what that might be), and not with Plot.

Comment: `f` and `x` do not explicitly appear in the argument of `With`, so `With` does nothing here. Try `Block` instead of `With`. `With` replaces explicit occurrences of `x` and `f` while `Block` assigns a value to them temporarily. However, something *is* wrong with this PDF: it does not integrate to 1. See also `Method -> "Normalize"` for `ProbabilityDistribution`

Comment: I suspected so. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Szabolcs, A question on Normalize and my PDF. Are there instances where a PDF requires Normalize, or is the requirement of Normalize on a PDF a certain indication that the method that created the PDF is wrong? (Normalization worked in my case)